# Local or Remote repository depending on config

Tags: java, spring

I'am creating api which will serve infomation about movies. I want to fetch information about movies from two sources:

1. DB which will be populated with some example data
2. Remote API

I will have flag in properties file, for exmample fetch_from_remote = true/false;

My problem is how to structure my project. I thought about something like the code below. I will inject one of two implemantations of MovieRepo (LocalRepo or RemoteRepo) into MovieService depening on flag. But I'm not shure if it will work or not and if it is good apporach? Do you have any advices/better ideas?

MovieController.class

```
public class MovieController{
    MovieService MovieService;

     Movie getMovie(int id){
         MovieService.getMovie(id);
     }
}
```

MovieRepository.class

```
public interface MovieRepository{

    Movie getMovie(int id);
}
```

RemoteRepo.class

```
public class RemoteRepo implements MovieRepoisotry (

        public getMovie(int id){
            // implemenatation to connect to remotApi and fetchData
        }
)
```

LocalRepo.class

```
public interface LocalRepo extends  MovieRepository,JpaRepository<ChatMessage, Integer>{

}
```

MovieService.class

```
public class MovieService{
MovieRepository MovieRepository;


public getMovie(int id){
    MovieRepository.getMovie(id);
}

}
```

Comment: *I'm not shure if it will work or not*: why don't you test it then?

Comment: look at `@ConditionalOnProperty` to  let spring create bean for you based on property.

Comment: @JBNizet it will take some time to test it and I wanted to avoid wasting time, even if it will work maybe there is better approach to that problem

Comment: @michalk thanks, it might be useful

Comment: I would recommend instead of setting flag "fetch_from_remote"  in a property file, set it and read it from some database table. So that you never ever have to go into the code or property file to make changes. If null in database table, you can run some default function/method. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you use springboot, I recommend to use application properties per environment. For local use application-local.properties, for dev application-dev.properties etc. Add environment specific configuration details in specific properties. When running, you need to provide 'spring.profiles.active' property as vm argument with value either local or dev etc.